# Transition (many to many join) tables in MySQL; allowing for duplicate entries to link 1 column to multiple other columns in different table

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

Ok, so I am going to try and be specific as possible but my MySQL skills are pretty weak. So here is the situation:

I have 2 tables: Donor and Students. A donor can be linked to as many students as they want and each student can be linked to as many donors as donors want to "claim" them. So if I have Sally, a student, she can have Jim, a donor, and Jeff, a donor, be linked to her. So, I have all my students in one table and all my donors in another table. I need to put them together show the students name, id and the id of all the donors that the student is linked to.

Currently my tables are: Donor with DonorID, FirstName, LastName, DonorType, StreetAddress, etc. Then Students with: StudentID, FirstName, LastName and DonorID. However, that only allows me to link a student with one donor. So, I was thinking I need to make a transition table that would allow me to show the StudentID, FirstName(of student), LastName(of student), and the DonorID that "claims" that student and allow for me to duplicate StudentID and put a different DonorID in the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, so on and so on entries of the same student.

So, I guess my question is how do transition tables work in MySQL; I believe I am going to need to work with the JOIN function and join the two tables together but after reading about that on tizag.com I am even more confused. I have worked with Access where when you create a transition table you can pull the PK from each table and create a composite key using the two keys from the other tables but I am not quite sure how to do that in MySQL; does it work essentially the same and I should be pulling the PK from each table and linking them together in the 3rd, transition, table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marvin's right.

You need three tables to pull this off.

Donor

```
DonorID
FirstName
LastName
DonorType
StreetAddress
etc.
```

Student

```
 StudentID
 FirstName
 LastName
 etc.
```

Then you need Student_Donor.  This is often called a join table, and implements the many-to-many relationship.

```
StudentID   (PK)  (FK to Student)
DonorID     (PK)  (FK to Donor)
DonorOrdinal
```

If StudentID = 5 has four donors with ID = 6,7,11,15, then you'l have these rows

```
StudentId   DonorId   DonorOrdinal
    5         6          1
    5         7          2
    5        11          3
    5        15          4
```

The DonorOrdinal column allows you to specify a student's primary donor and secondary donors.  I can't tell from your question how important that is, but it's helpful to be able to order these things.  Remember this: formally speaking, a SQL SELECT query returns rows in an unpredictable order unless you also specify ORDER BY.

If you want to display your students and their donors, you'll need this query:

```
      SELECT s.StudentID, s.FirstName, s.LastName, 
             sd.DonorOrdinal, 
             d.DonorType, d.DonorID, d.FirstName, d.LastName
        FROM student s
   LEFT JOIN student_donor sd ON s.StudentID = sd.StudentID
   LEFT JOIN donor d ON sd.DonorID = d.DonorID
    ORDER BY s.StudentID, sd.DonorOrdinal, d.DonorID
```

This will show you all students (whether having donors or not per LEFT JOIN) in order of ID, then their donors in order of DonorOrdinal.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. Sorry if my question was confusing. This worked great though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The most confusing question is the one you don't ask. One of the things to do is "accept" a useful answer to your question -- that helps the system keep track of helpful answers.

Comment: Haha, thanks sorry for not accepting it. I just read on a different question I was reading where people were getting on a guy about it so I just came back here to accept your answer. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pretty much.  What you are talking about is a Many to Many relationship.  Your donor table should not include a reference to the student table (and vice versa).  You'll need a new table (what you are calling a transition table) that contains the DonorId and StudentId.  This can comprise your primary key or you can use another column for the primary key that is an auto_increment.